# How effective & acceptable is cold calling the prospective employers than emailing?

Tags: job-search

I am passively looking for the job openings in my field. Few days back I found a job opening on a job portal. Shall I call the recruiter to ask a few queries or shall I just send an email and wait for their reply?

Comment: What industry? This will vary a lot, based on industry.

Comment: Also location. Culture can play a huge role in whether this is acceptable practice or not.

Comment: Some companies may have resume submission links, or drop boxes. The whole point of those is because they don't want to deal with cold calls. Overall I would rate your chances of success as very low.

Comment: @enderland I am working in a manufacturing company and looking for the jobs in same industry.

Comment: It doesn't matter much, call or email.

Comment: @Thebluefish I am from India.

Comment: This is not cold calling. There is a job opening on a portal. It's just calling. Cold calling is when you have no reason to believe they're hiring, but you call them anyway and ask for a job.

Comment: What's a successful call going to get? A request for you to forward your resume in email?

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks for correcting. I was mixing two different things.

Answer (score 3):

When responding to a job application, I feel that you should follow the job application process outlined in the advert.

Clearly that doesn't apply for cold-calling (though applying to a link on a job portal *isn't* cold-calling, as Kate notes). However, the principle behind that does; one of the reasons you follow the process when applying for an advertised job is because hiring managers are busy doing other things and wish to manage their time, e.g. to respond to your queries when its convenient for them.

Emailing them rather than calling allows them to do the same thing and this is therefore what I'd recommend *as a second choice* to following the actual instructions on any actual job post, if you have one. You don't want potential employers to remember you as a pain in the backside.

Answer (score 0):

If you have their direct email, send them an email expressing your interest. Since you say you're passively looking, I would leave it to a short introduction email introducing yourself and opening up the lines of communication. That can actually work to your benefit considering how many cover letters and resumes a hiring manager can get for one position. Often times a short personalized email can open the communication channels and lend toward them asking you for your resume; and since they did the asking, you would be more likely to be at the top of their stack as opposed to the one of many dozens of people who sent him/her resumes.

On the other hand, if you're email a generic email or an aliased email where you don't know that you're reaching the decision maker, a brief call can be a better option and even enable you to circumvent some of the process, giving you a more direct channel as well. As previously mentioned, it all depends on the industry. Know the etiquette and practices of your industry before proceeding.

Comment: *a brief call can be a better option and even enable you to circumvent some of the process* - this very much depends on the company. Larger organisations might very well require you to follow their process because that's all they can do, smaller organisations might well have managers who will not be happy to have their day interrupted by people who cannot follow the process. If there's a process there, follow it.